# Toggle function not working when called

Tags: javascript, toggle

The idea is to make two *div* appear or disappear based on the click.  The CSS display style is set to none.
Any help is appreciated.

```
   <div id="mainOval">
        <form id="btns">
            <input type="button" value="Timer" id="timerBtn" onclick="displayCont('Timer')"/>
            <input type="button" value="Countdown" id="ctDownBtn" onclick="displayCont('Countdown')"/>
        </form> 
</div>
<div id="Timer">
</div>
<div id="Countdown"> 
</div> 



<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayCont(inp)
        {
            var ele = document.getElementById(inp);
            var shown = ele.style.display;
            if (shown == 'none') 
                {
                    ele.style.display = 'block';
                }
            else if (shown == 'block')
                {
                    ele.style.display = 'none';
                }
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You are never changing of the attributes of the element, simply setting the value for `shown`. You need to actually change the display css value for something to happen.

Comment: Does your code really have spaces between the equals signs in your `if()` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
if (shown == 'none') {
    ele.style.display = 'block';
}
else if (shown == 'block'){
    ele.style.display = 'none';
}
```

You have ot set the style of the element, not just assign a Javascript variable. And equality is `==`, not `= =`.

Comment: You don't have a `style` attribute in your elements. `ele.style.display` doesn't get the computed style from CSS, it just gets whatever is in the `style="XXX"` attribute.